# How to extract xml data into a specific reusable list?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

Given a generic XML file, I wanted to parse the data so it's in a list for later use. For instance, for the XML data below, I would like to have the data stored in a variable as:

`[['country name=Liechtenstein', 'rank=2'],['country name=Liechtenstein', 'actions', 'name= PC'], ['country name=Liechtenstein', 'actions', 'type= 7'], ['country name=Liechtenstein', 'actions', 'type=7'], ['country name=Liechtenstein', 'actions', 'properties', 'name=filename'], ...etc]`

I know it looks a little messy, but my goal is to incorporate this list into tkinter for the user to pick the fields they want to change (like if they wanted to change data under actions/name PC to Linux). I was able to get the children using ElementTree, but I am not able to get the tags that it was associated with and its parent tags. If the format of the list could be made more clear or easier to interpret please let me know.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <data>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
            <actions>
                <name>PC</name>
                <type>7</type>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>filename</name>
                        <value>unknown</value>
                        <conditions>
                            <name>Nothing </name> 
                        </conditions>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </actions>
            <year>2008</year>
            <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
            <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
        </country>
    </data>
```

Comment: Please add your solution so that it is easier to debug any errors

Comment: @DerMechaniker I haven't been able to figure it out yet, but I was thinking about taking a recursive route. I'll add something as soon as I can.

Comment: How is that a useful list for other applications? You remove the tree structure of relationships into concatenated strings.

Comment: @Parfait I was thinking maybe I could locate/edit that location in the string afterwards, would that be possible?